# How to solve 'A footer of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page'?

Tags: javascript, macos, ms-word, footer, sections

I want to open a document as pdf with this function:

Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Pdf, { sliceSize: 65536 }, function (result) { });

In Windows (Word 2016) this works correctly, but on Mac (Word for Mac) it shows this error message:
A footer of section 1 is set outside the printable area of the page. Do you want to continue?

As workaround i can alter the footer settings (use 2 cm instead of 1.25 cm). Another option is to install a printer. Both ways it fixes the issue, but... what if i do NOT want to alter the footer settings and i do NOT have a printer?

How can this error message be solved?